If the user_action field in the /v2/checkout/orders interface is pay_now, is a capture order required?
Currently, the one-time payment function is implemented through /v2/checkout/orders interface。
If the user_action field in the /v2/checkout/orders interface is pay_now, is a capture order required?
is a capture order required?

Yes, after an order is created and then approved by a payer, it must be captured for there to be a completed payment. If there is no capture, no money will move.
For redirect integrations, the default user_action is CONTINUE. Setting it to PAY_NOW does not change any functionality, it only changes the text of the last button at PayPal.

If after that last button is clicked the capture is going to occur immediately, the user_action should be PAY_NOW.

If after that last button is clicked there is going to be a final review step before capture, the user_action should be CONTINUE.


Anything else is a wrong integration.
